# How to add data- attributes to a field in alpacajs?

Tags: alpacajs

I am using alpacaJs 1.5.23.

I need to add data-(like data-target) attributes to my fields. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this by using data property in options object of your alpaca configuration like this:

```
"data": {
   "target": "test value"
}
```

[image]

here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/3uk2mxLv/) for this.